# Play 2.1.1 - Not binding simple select

Tags: data-binding, playframework-2.0

I have a frustrating problem with Play 2.1.1

I revisited an existing page which was working fine and added a couple of simple select statements (not multi-select). No matter what I do the values are not getting bound to the Form on bindRequest()

Here is what I have done until now.

1. Did `alert(document.forms[0].mySelectField.value)` before submit in the view (I can see the value)
2. Ran: `play reload, play clean, play clean-all, play complile` (No use)
3. If I replace the select statement with an text box of same name Play binds it okay.
4. Printed `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()` in Controller. It does not even see the select field (except in case of point 3 above).

mySelectField in MyForm is private. But it has public getter/setter.

It is a simple problem but I have been at this for 4 hours now. Any suggestions? Thanks.

View:

```
<input type="text" value="Y" name="mySelectField" />
<!--
<select id="mySelectField" name"mySelectField" style="width: 180px;">
 <option value="">All</option>                                               
 <option value="Y">Yes</option>
<option value="N">No</option>
</select>   
-->
```

Form:

```
private String mySelectField;
public String getMySelectField() {
    return mySelectField;
}
public void setMySelectField(String mySelectField) {
    this.mySelectField= mySelectField;
}
```

Controller:

```
Form<MyForm> myFormP = Form.form(MyForm.class); 
MyForm myForm = myFormP.bindFromRequest().get();
System.out.println("B. "+myForm.getMySelectField());
System.out.println("Form: "+request().body().asFormUrlEncoded());
```

Comment: And yes, I have checked that the new select field is within the form tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Play is concerned, there's no difference between a text field and a select. Both are encoded values in the request. I suggest you use the dev tools in chrome or firefox to see the differences in the submitted requests.

Comment: Thanks! I did as you suggested and looked away from Play and at other things. The problem was that I missed = between the name and "mySelectField" in select. Can't believe I wasted half a day on this.